# Rotate an ImageView clockwise using ObjectAnimator

Tags: android, animation, canvas, bitmap

I am trying to rotate an Image so that it fits properly below another Image. So this is what I am trying to achieve :

[image: What I am trying to achieve]

And this is what I am able to achieve :

[image: Currently achieved]

It basically contains two `ImageView` with the first one containing the part above the floor and the second one containing the tiles to cover the floor.

My problem is that I am unable to animate the the tiles image in clockwise direction as well as rotate the view around x axis such that it fits below the image containing the part above the floor.

I am using `ObjectAnimator` to animate my `ImageView`. Below is my code:

```
public class VisualizerFragment extends Fragment {

ImageView image;
FlipImageView image_back;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(
            ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_visualizer, container, false);
    image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.vs_image);
    image_back = (FlipImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.vs_image_back);

    Glide.with(getActivity())
            .load(R.drawable.floor3)
            .centerCrop()
            .fitCenter()
            .listener(new RequestListener<Integer, GlideDrawable>() {
                @Override
                public boolean onException(Exception e, Integer model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, Integer model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getActivity().getResources(), R.drawable.i9004);

                    //crop image
                    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                    matrix.postScale(1f, 1f);
                    Bitmap croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0,100, 100, matrix, true);

                    bmp = getRoundedCornerBitmap(croppedBitmap, getResources().getColor(R.color.line),0,1,getActivity());
                    BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(bmp);
                    bitmapDrawable.setTileModeXY(Shader.TileMode.REPEAT, Shader.TileMode.REPEAT);

                    image_back.setDrawable(bitmapDrawable);
                    image_back.setFlippedDrawable(bitmapDrawable);
                    image_back.setFlipped(true);
                    image_back.toggleFlip();

                    //rotate image
                    ObjectAnimator anim = (ObjectAnimator) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(getActivity(), R.animator.fliping);
                    anim.setTarget(image_back);
                    anim.setDuration(100);
                    anim.start();


                    return false;

                }
            })
            .into(image);


    return view;
}


public static Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int color, int cornerDips, int borderDips, Context context) {
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int borderSizePx = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, (float) borderDips,
            context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    final int cornerSizePx = 0;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);

    // prepare canvas for transfer

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, cornerSizePx, cornerSizePx, paint);

    // draw bitmap
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);


    // draw border
    paint.setColor(color);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth((float) borderSizePx);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, cornerSizePx, cornerSizePx, paint);

    return output;
}
}
```

And below is my fliping.xml used for the animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:propertyName="rotationX"
    android:valueFrom="20"
    android:valueTo="50"
    android:valueType="floatType"
/>
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? Is it rotating at all, or is nothing happening?

Comment: please i do not get you, sorry could you elaborate more more

Comment: see difference in images....the first one is desired and the second one is output...he needs output as first image

Comment: Have you tried creating a larger tile image (so, basically the with a w and h == the hypotenuse) so that it's larger than the window at any rotation, and then use clip the rect to not draw the area that's off screen?

Answer (score 3):

well i have found a solution for this....remove object animator and instead use this code

```
camera.save();

            camera.rotateX(790);
            camera.rotateY(2.5f);
            camera.rotateZ(140);

            camera.translate(170,0, -8);

            camera.getMatrix(matrix);
            camera.restore();
```

create your custom image class and use this in applyTransformation()

Answer (score 0):

Try below code after simply loading the image

```
        ObjectAnimator imageViewObjectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageview ,
                "rotation", 20f, 50f);
        imageViewObjectAnimator.setDuration(1000); // miliseconds
        imageViewObjectAnimator.start();
```